# Remove the alias name from the json object in stream analytics

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I use the UDF.Javascript function to process the message,when after converting to json object ,I see the UDF.Javascript alias name getting added to the json.

{"Device":{"deviceId":"DJT3COE4","productFilter":"pcmSensor","SignalDetails":[{"Devicevalue":"72.04","DisplayName":"Valve Open Status","Description":"Machine Valve Open State Information","DataType":"BOOLEAN","Precision":"undefined","DefaultUoM":"undefined"},{"Devicevalue":"2.7","DisplayName":"Temperature","Description":"Temperature Sensor Reading","DataType":"TEMPERATURE","Precision":"2","DefaultUoM":"DEG_CELSIUS"},{"Devicevalue":"2.99","DisplayName":"Location","Description":"Location","DataType":"LOCATION","Precision":"undefined","DefaultUoM":"LAT_LONG"},{"Devicevalue":"15","DisplayName":"Valve Control","Description":"On / Off control","DataType":"BOOLEAN","Precision":"undefined","DefaultUoM":"undefined"}]}}

Remove the aliasname  : {"Device": from the json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use `WITH...AS...` in your sql,please see below example:

```
WITH 
c AS
(
    SELECT 
    udf.processArray(input)
    from input
) 

SELECT
    c.processarray.item,c.processarray.name
INTO
    output
FROM
    c
```

Output:

[image]

My columns are very few,you need to define all of your columns which is a little bit tedious.But it does works,please have a try.